# C# initialize list so not null if no items added

Tags: c#, initialization, generic-list

I have a routine which initializes a list ...

```
var items = new List<TodoItem>();
//... load items from a REST service ...
return items;
```

A subsequent routine tries to enumerate the list ...

```
foreach (var i in items)
{
    // ...
}
```

If the portal doesn't return any items, the list is `null` and the attempt to enumerate it fails ... the reasons have already been discussed.

Till now I did a `!= null` check before the enumeration. Now I read a SO post where someone suggest that it was "bad practice" to return `null` in case a list has no items.

How do I initialize the list as an empty list which can be enumerated, instead of letting it be `null`? the only way that came to my mind was a sequence like

```
var items = new List<TodoItem>();
items =  Enumerable.Empty<TodoItem>()
```

This won't compile:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

Trying to use an explicit cast ...

```
items = (List<TodoItem>)Enumerable.Empty<TodoItem>();
```

fails with a runtime exception "invalid cast"

Can anybode advise how I can properly initialize my list?

Comment: We need to know what `... load items from a REST service ...` _actually is_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var items = new List<TodoItem>();
```

Creates an empty list. Done.

If you're doing this and it ends up being `null`, then your code is setting it to `null` and you haven't shown that code. Maybe it has something to do with your *"load items from a REST service"* code?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, for your comment. Looking deeper in the portal code (which I considered irrelevant, but in fact it is the problem) I found an exception handler:
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(nameof(GetTodoDataAsync), "Error: " + ex.Message, "OK");
                return null;
            }
This is where the null comes from.